# Change the permission of generated hive file

Tags: unix, hadoop, hive

I am exporting data from hive to text file saved to the local file system using the query below:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/local/file/system/directory'
  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  NULL DEFINED AS ''
  SELECT * FROM staging_table WHERE date='2017-05-28';
```

The query generates the file as expected but I am having problem deleting the file because of the permission.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hive hive 12345 May 31 13:03 000000_0
```

Is it possible to change the permission or owner of the file?

Answer (score 0):

You will need Sudo or root access for doing this:

```
sudo chown -R NewOwnerName:NewGroupName /local/file/system/directory
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in linus just change the permission to 777 then that should be editable to any users

```
sudo chmod -R 777 directoryPath
```

or

```
sudo chmod 777 filePath
```

If you are root user you wouldn't need sudo

If you are in windows use icacls

```
C:\>icacls "D:\test" /grant John:(OI)(CI)F /T
```

According do MS documentation:

```
F = Full Control
CI = Container Inherit - This flag indicates that subordinate containers will inherit this ACE.
OI = Object Inherit - This flag indicates that subordinate files will inherit the ACE.
/T = Apply recursively to existing files and sub-folders. (OI and CI only apply to new files and sub-folders). Credit: comment by @AlexSpence
```

.